# using j-query datepicker that displays only month and year

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use the j-query date picker to only show the month and the year but my problem is the date-picker pops up or works only when if i first click the text-box that holds the date-picker but if i click the other text-box first;  then i try to click the date-picker text-box it does not work. What am i doing wrong here?  here is my code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Facility:">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFacilityType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Facility") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFacilityType" runat="server" Width="180" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Facility") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1_SR" runat="server" CssClass="popupControl">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1_SR" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1_Facility" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="FacilityType_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="140px">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="East"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="South"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <br />
                        <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1_SR" runat="server" CommitProperty="value"
                            PopupControlID="Panel1_SR" Position="Bottom" TargetControlID="txtFacilityType">
                        </ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select Month/Year:">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Month_Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInputDate" runat="server" CssClass="date-picker"></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

and here is the script for the date-picker

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $().ready(function () {
            $('.date-picker').mousedown(function () {
                $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

How about changing the code like this. Your function should trigger when you press the mouse button over the text box with class "date-picker".

Also instead of this line `<asp:TextBox ID="txtInputDate" runat="server" CssClass="date-picker"></asp:TextBox>`   add `<input name="txtInputDate" id="txtInputDate" runat="server" class="date-picker" />`

Comment: thanks, i tried that but still doing the same thing.  for some reason it does not like when i click the Facility text box first but the date-picker will work fine if i don't click any other text box.

Comment: Please see the update answer and advise if there are any results.

Comment: it seems it does not work after the page does post pack but it only works the first time and when the post pack occurs then it does not work.  I have to refresh the page or hit f5 in order the date picker to work again.  thanks